# Can't override CSS padding

Tags: css, google-chrome

I've got the following CSS that is being applied to tables:

```
.myTable
{
  width: 99%;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  word-wrap:break-word;
  border:1px solid #28282C;
  background-color: #F7F6F3;
}

.myTable td
{    
  padding: 16px 4px 0px 4px;
  text-align:left;
  vertical-align:top;    
}
```

Because I don't want that padding applied to form elements in my tables, I also have this CSS:

```
.myTable td input
{    
  padding:0px 0px 0px 0px !important;     
}
```

However, this doesn't work. The padding stubbornly stays put, UNLESS I put in a larger padding. For example, if I do this:

```
.myTable td input
{    
  padding:50px 50px 50px 50px !important;     
}
```

Then the form elements are correctly overridden with the newer, gigantic padding. What am I missing here? How do I override/cancel padding on child elements using CSS?

**Edit:** I figured it out after digging through the rendered HTML. The input elements were fine, the cause was that ASP.NET renders each checkbox in a checkboxlist in its own TD, which was receiving the padding from the stylesheet and making it seem like the inputs were being padded. Thanks everyone

Comment: Can't see the effect: http://jsfiddle.net/snMtK/.

Comment: @eskimoblood: Remember to untick _normalized CSS_ in jsFiddle to remove their CSS reset rules. ;-)

Comment: Sure, but after all the described problem should not happen. So in my mind the problem has nothing to do with the pasted code.

Comment: You're right, it was ASP.NET's method of rendering the controls. There are penalties to abstraction :)

Comment: yes...both .net and jsf/p are notorious for having REALLY crappy HTML if you just let it output stuff on its own. You definitely want to be writing custom controls to make sure you have full control over the rendered HTML.

Answer (score 2):

that's working exactly as you typed it. You have applied padding to the TD. That applies padding to every TD regardless of what's in it.

Your second style for the input would be *in addition to* the padding set on the TD. So it's not over-writing anything.

You could try applying negative margin to the INPUT to counter the padding in the parent TD. Not sure if all browsers will like that or not.

Alternatively, give the TD's that have the input their own class:

```
<td class="withInput">
```

Then you can use this selector in your css:

```
td.withInput {padding: 0px;}
```

Comment: Doesn't he ask for the padding in the input field not in the td?

Comment: heh...oops! That should have been negative MARGIN. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @eskimoblood, my interpretation of the question is that he doesn't want there to be space around the INPUT fields when in the table. Since the space is being created by the padding on the TD itself, that's what has to be modified.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with your code. You can even remove the CSS for the INPUT.
INPUT will not inherit padding values from parent TD.
Show us the page, so we can help you.

The only issue you will have is with IE7 and older. In that case use NEGATIVE MARGIN for your INPUT elements.

Hacks for IE7 and IE6

```
input{
*margin: -2px;
_margin: -2px;
}
```